# Jquery: add existing function to an Jquery event

Tags: jquery

in all jquery examples i see this kind of code:

```
$('.menu a').each(function(){
 $(this).animate({paddingLeft: $(this).width()}, 200);
 });
```

What they do here is create a function 'on the fly' (is that called an anonymous delegate?)

but what if i have an existing function, which wants to have access to the $(this) also?

let's say i have this function:

```
function doAnimate(ctl){
  //do something here
{
```

How can i use that function in the jquery statement?

Reason i ask is that i want to use this function in more jquery statements, and i don't want to type the anonymous delegate multiple times.

I've tried this, but that gives me an error:

```
$("#<%=txtReceiverEmailEcard1.ClientID  %>").blur(blurWatermark($(this), 'Your email address'));
```

Comment: Correct, 'on the fly' is anonymous function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from the jQuery [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

> More importantly, the callback is
>   fired in the context of the current
>   DOM element, so the keyword this
>   refers to the element.

And the signature of the method is

> .each( function(index, Element) )
>
> function(index, Element)A function to
>   execute for each matched element.

You can then write

```
$('.menu a').each(myFunction)

function myFunction(index, Element) { 
    alert(this); /* this points to the element */
}
```

That basically means that you can get all kind of nice information (like index) to your callback.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
$('.menu a').each(doAnimate)
```

Wherever an anonymous function works, a reference to a "normal" one works just as well. :) Then you need to use the function parameters like

```
function doAnimate (index, elem) {
    $(elem).animate({paddingLeft: $(elem).width()}, 200);
}
```

Comment: and can i pass the `$(this)` also?

Comment: reason i ask is that it doesn't work right now, i've edited the question

Comment: Sorry, the function parameters need to be (index, Element) instead of just (Element), edited my answer. See http://api.jquery.com/each/ :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
$('.menu a').each(function(){
    doAnimate($(this));
});
```

If its a reusable one then develop a [**plugin**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) that you can easily associate with jQuery objects.